# My CSS Padding and Margins are showing up but not declared

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I'm trying to fix my website. Problem #1 I can't push the list on the header over by using margin-left or padding-left. [Problem #2 the Main Header 1 and 3 are creating there own padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86OsM.jpg). My goal is to fix the padding and bring the headers closer together and get rid of this padding/margin issue.

```css
#hlist {
  top: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: -12px;
}

ul#hlist {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul#hlist li {
  float: left;
}

ul#hlist li a {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

ul#hlist li a:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: gray;
  color: gray;
}

.content-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

.text-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -60%;
}

.text-wrapper h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.text-wrapper h3 {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="hlist">
    <li><a href="#">WHERE TO WATCH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="logo-box">
    <img style="height: 32px; padding:5px;" src="https://assets.nationalgeographic.com/styleguide/stable/logos/ng-logo-2fl.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <image id="bg" src="https://i.imgur.com/i2MSrn7.jpg">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3> The Giant </h3>
      <h1> Panda </h1>
    </div>
    <image id="ply" style="height: 32px; padding:5px;" src="images.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: you have an end header tag in this code where there is no beginning header tag. Swap out the div id=header for a <header> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `body` has `margin: 8px` set. That's why there's a gap around the edges. Set `margin: 0` on the `body` tag. Check out this [codepen I created](https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/pen/rNVQLre?editors=1100). That solves the gap around the edges of the image.

I don't fully understand the second part of your question. Your page is spread out very wide due to the size of the image. Make the image smaller and so that it doesn't overflow and your site will look much better.

If you want to position the links in an easier way look into using `Flexbox` and doing something like this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

Do that on your links and they should float right if that's what you're trying to do.

Also, look into using a [CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). By default HTML elements come with certain CSS styles applied automatically. A reset will get rid of default styles so they don't interfere with what you're trying to do. Lots of HTML elements have default padding/margins that you may not realize.

Comment: The second question is referring to the header padding like in this [link](https://imgur.com/0SJfRiE) image. On my end the body was already set for margin 0. ```* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}```

Comment: The padding on the `h1` is most likely the standard padding/margin that `h1's` come with. Explicitly set the padding  and margin to 0 or use a CSS Reset.